# How to install jdk7 on CentOS?

Tags: java

I'm trying to install jdk7 on my CentOS 6.5 machine. Actually, I thought I already did this 6 months ago but when I type `java -version` I see `javac 1.6.0_30`.

I've downloaded jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz, verified checksum, then extracted to `/home/username/java/jdk7u25/jdk1.7.0_25`.

Then I edited my `.bash_profile` file, which includes:

```
...
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
...
export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

when I type `source .bash_profile` then `java -version` I still see the same 1.6 version noted above. Anyone know what else needs to be done?

Comment: ... You're adding the new Java paths after your already-existing path.

Comment: export PATH=$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: Another java is being found in PATH before the java that you are installing. Change  export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin to export PATH=$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only be editing your `PATH` if you have to install a personal copy of Java. If you are going that route then you need to make sure that the `bin` directory of your preferred version of Java is at the beginning of your `PATH`, like so:

```
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But the better way to handle this is to install Java and use the `alternatives` command. If you can get by with OpenJDK you could just try:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

As OpenJDK is installed it will run the `alternatives` command to correctly configure everything. If you want to use the Oracle JDK then you can use either the RPM or the tar.gz, the RPM installed in `/usr/java` while the tar.gz should probably be extracted to that directory or another non-user specific directory like `/opt/java` or something. Personally I'd recommend the RPMs so install would be something like:

```
yum localinstall jdk-8u5-linux-x64.rpm
yum localinstall jdk-8u5-linux-x64-demos.rpm
```

After install comes the `alternatives` command however most people and docs get lazy (look at the CentOS wiki page that the other answer points to for an example of what I mean by lazy). You really should use the `alternatives` command to setup not only `java` and `javac` but also all the other commands that come with Java AND the man pages for those commands. You should run like:

```
jdk=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05
jre=$jdk/jre

alternatives \
  --install /usr/bin/java java $jre/bin/java 180005 \
  --slave /usr/lib/jvm/jre jre $jre \
  --slave /usr/bin/keytool keytool $jre/bin/keytool \
  --slave /usr/bin/orbd orbd $jre/bin/orbd \
  --slave /usr/bin/pack200 pack200 $jre/bin/pack200 \
  --slave /usr/bin/rmid rmid $jre/bin/rmid \
  --slave /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistry $jre/bin/rmiregistry \
  --slave /usr/bin/servertool servertool $jre/bin/servertool \
  --slave /usr/bin/tnameserv tnameserv $jre/bin/tnameserv \
  --slave /usr/bin/unpack200 unpack200 $jre/bin/unpack200 \
  --slave /usr/bin/javaws javaws $jre/bin/javaws \
  --slave /usr/bin/jjs jjs $jre/bin/jjs \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/java.1 java.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/java.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1 keytool.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/keytool.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/orbd.1 orbd.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/ordb.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/pack200.1 pack200.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/pack200.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmid.1 rmid.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/rmid.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmiregistry.1 rmiregistry.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/rmiregistry.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/servertool.1 servertool.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/servertool.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/tnameserv.1 tnameserv.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/tnameserv.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/unpack200.1 unpack200.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/unpack200.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javaws.1 javaws.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javaws.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jjs.1 jjs.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jjs.1

alternatives \
  --install /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0 \
  jre_1.8.0 $jre 180005 \

alternatives \
  --install /usr/bin/javac javac $jdk/bin/javac 180005 \
  --slave /usr/lib/jvm/java java_sdk $jdk \
  --slave /usr/bin/appletviewer appletviewer $jdk/bin/appletviewer \
  --slave /usr/bin/extcheck extcheck $jdk/bin/extcheck \
  --slave /usr/bin/idlj idlj $jdk/bin/idlj \
  --slave /usr/bin/jar jar $jdk/bin/jar \
  --slave /usr/bin/jarsigner jarsigner $jdk/bin/jarsigner \
  --slave /usr/bin/javadoc javadoc $jdk/bin/javadoc \
  --slave /usr/bin/javafxpackager javafxpackager $jdk/bin/javafxpackager \
  --slave /usr/bin/javah javah $jdk/bin/javah \
  --slave /usr/bin/javap javap $jdk/bin/javap \
  --slave /usr/bin/jcmd jcmd $jdk/bin/jcmd \
  --slave /usr/bin/jconsole jconsole $jdk/bin/jconsole \
  --slave /usr/bin/jdb jdb $jdk/bin/jdb \
  --slave /usr/bin/jdeps jdeps $jdk/bin/jdeps \
  --slave /usr/bin/jhat jhat $jdk/bin/jhat \
  --slave /usr/bin/jinfo jinfo $jdk/bin/jinfo \
  --slave /usr/bin/jmap jmap $jdk/bin/jmap \
  --slave /usr/bin/jmc jmc $jdk/bin/jmc \
  --slave /usr/bin/jps jps $jdk/bin/jps \
  --slave /usr/bin/jrunscript jrunscript $jdk/bin/jrunscript \
  --slave /usr/bin/jsadebugd jsadebugd $jdk/bin/jsadebugd \
  --slave /usr/bin/jstack jstack $jdk/bin/jstack \
  --slave /usr/bin/jstat jstat $jdk/bin/jstat \
  --slave /usr/bin/jstatd jstatd $jdk/bin/jstatd \
  --slave /usr/bin/jvisualvm jvisualvm $jdk/bin/jvisualvm \
  --slave /usr/bin/native2ascii native2ascii $jdk/bin/native2ascii \
  --slave /usr/bin/policytool policytool $jdk/bin/policytool \
  --slave /usr/bin/rmic rmic $jdk/bin/rmic \
  --slave /usr/bin/schemagen schemagen $jdk/bin/schemagen \
  --slave /usr/bin/serialver serialver $jdk/bin/serialver \
  --slave /usr/bin/wsgen wsgen $jdk/bin/wsgen \
  --slave /usr/bin/wsimport wsimport $jdk/bin/wsimport \
  --slave /usr/bin/xjc xjc $jdk/bin/xjc \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/appletviewer.1 appletviewer.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/appletviewer.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/extcheck.1 extcheck.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/extcheck.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/idlj.1 idlj.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/idlj.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jar.1 jar.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jar.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jarsigner.1 jarsigner.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jarsigner.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1 javac.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javac.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javadoc.1 javadoc.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javadoc.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javafxpackager.1 javafxpackager.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javafxpackager.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javah.1 javah.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javah.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/javap.1 javap.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/javap.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jcmd.1 jcmd.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jcmd.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jconsole.1 jconsole.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jconsole.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jdb.1 jdb.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jdb.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jdeps.1 jdeps.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jdeps.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jhat.1 jhat.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jhat.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jinfo.1 jinfo.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jinfo.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jmap.1 jmap.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jmap.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jmc.1 jmc.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jmc.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jps.1 jps.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jps.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jrunscript.1 jrunscript.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jrunscript.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jsadebugd.1 jsadebugd.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jsadebugd.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstack.1 jstack.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jstack.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstat.1 jstat.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jstat.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jstatd.1 jstatd.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jstatd.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/jvisualvm.1 jvisualvm.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/jvisualvm.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/native2ascii.1 native2ascii.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/native2ascii.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/policytool.1 policytool.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/policytool.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/rmic.1 rmic.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/rmic.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/schemagen.1 schemagen.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/schemagen.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/serialver.1 serialver.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/serialver.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/wsgen.1 wsgen.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/wsgen.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/wsimport.1 wsimport.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/wsimport.1 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/xjc.1 xjc.1 \
  $jdk/man/man1/xjc.1

alternatives \
  --install /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0 \
  java_sdk_1.8.0 $jdk 180005 \
```

That is my example for JDK 8 but if you swap out the `jdk=` line for your path that will come close but there are a couple of new commands that come with 8 and one that was dropped from 8 so some slight adjustments would be needed if you really wanted to install 7. Also note the `1800005` number. With the `alternatives` command the higher number is the default selection and OpenJDK 7u55 uses 170055. If you pick a number lower than the number used by whatever OpenJDK you have installed you'll need to run `alternatives --config java` and `alternatives --config javac`.

After running the `alternatives` commands you want to update you man page keyword database by running `makewhatis`.

Then you might want to install the Java plugin for your Firefox:

```
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins/
```

Then you'd want to add the Java Control Panel to your System->Preferences menu and setup JARs to be double-clicked on:

```
/bin/cp -fr /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/desktop/* /usr/share/
/bin/cp -fr /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/* /usr/share/icons/System
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/System
/usr/bin/update-desktop-database
```

If it wasn't clear, you'd do all this as `root`. If you don't have `root` then just use the tar.gz version and fix your `PATH`. I wrote a little bit more detail at http://blog.osdev.org/java/2014/04/22/jdk-alternatives.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably has link in /usr/bin/java to your another java installation directory.

Check [there](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaRuntimeEnvironment) about **alternatives** in CentOS

Comment: I don't have a `java` folder in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: You can then check what is path to your java binary by 

# _which java_